# My AppLocker Android App does not show the System Navigation Button on the Lock Screen

Tags: java, android-studio, popup, popupwindow

My AppLocker Android App does not show the System Navigation Button on the Lock Screen.  The status bar on the lock screen is also not working as I want.

I want when I open an app that I have locked, the lock screen should only be on that opened app.  The status bar and system navigation buttons should work normally.

I have obtained the Accessibility Permission and Appear on top Permission from the user.

```
package com.coremora.secure.lockScreens;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.andrognito.patternlockview.PatternLockView;
import com.andrognito.patternlockview.listener.PatternLockViewListener;
import com.andrognito.patternlockview.utils.PatternLockUtils;
import com.coremora.secure.R;
import java.util.List;

public class PatternLockScreen {

    static Dialog dialog;

    static SharedPreferences pref;

    static ImageView imageView;

    public static void PatternLockScreen(Context context, String packageName) {

        pref = context.getSharedPreferences("AppLocker", 0);

        dialog = new Dialog(context, R.style.Base_Theme_CoremoraSecure);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        View promptsView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pattern_lock_screen, null, false);

        imageView = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon_locked);

        try {

            Drawable icon = context.getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon(packageName);

            imageView.setImageDrawable(icon);

        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

        PatternLockView patternLockView = promptsView.findViewById(R.id.pattern_lock_view);

        patternLockView.addPatternLockListener(new PatternLockViewListener() {

            @Override

            public void onStarted() {

            }

            @Override

            public void onProgress(List<PatternLockView.Dot> progressPattern) {

            }

            @Override

            public void onCleared() {

            }

            @Override

            public void onComplete(List<PatternLockView.Dot> pattern) {

                String enterdPattern = PatternLockUtils.patternToString(patternLockView, pattern);

                if (enterdPattern.length() < 4){

                    patternLockView.clearPattern();

                    return;

                }

                if (enterdPattern.equals((pref.getString("code", "")))){

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }else {

                    patternLockView.clearPattern();

                }

            }

        });

        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY);

        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        dialog.setContentView(promptsView);

        dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        dialog.setOnKeyListener(new Dialog.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override

            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode,

                                 KeyEvent event) {

                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK

                        && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {

                    Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

                    startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

                    startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                    context.startActivity(startMain);

                }

                return true;

            }

        });

        dialog.show();
    }
}
```